# Publish Action NOT including class libraries comments.xml files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, class-library, xml-comments, kudu

I have a solution that has two projects, and a nuget package:
- `WebApp.csproj`
- `CommonClassLibrary.csproj`
- `nugetClassLibrary.nuget`

The WebApp has a project reference to `CommonClassLibrary.csproj`, and a nuget package reference to `nugetClassLibrary`. All 3 project's have xml comments enabled (using swashbuckle to build api docs).

Locally, the `CommonClassLibrary.xml` and `nugetClassLibrary` are correctly getting pulled over to the bin folder of the `WebApp.csproj`. **HOWEVER:** when a publish action occurs, the `CommonClassLibrary.xml` and `nugetClassLibrary.xml` files are not in the bin folder along with their corresponding dlls.

What is going on here?

**Update regarding nuget package hosting**
We have my own private nuget repository, and I am referencing a library via a nuget reference. that package is including the xml comments, but the wwwroot\bin after kudu install is not moving them.

**Update  Kudu tools directory info**
I have been sifting through the Kudu directories, and when I look at the `%home%\site\repository\MyApp\bin` directory, the comment xml files for project referenced class library is there, but not the nuget class library. When i download the nuget package referenced in the repository folder, I can see the xml file in the package.

**So it appears that the compilation is correctly building all of the xml files, but the kudu deployment is not including these additional xml files when deploying my hosting app.**

Comment: Does it get included if you do a 'Publish to file system' locally? This is more similar to what Kudu does

Comment: Just did a local publish, and I am not seeing the class library's xml comments file included.... since the file is not something i cam mark as content, i am no sure how to get this xml file to be included....

Comment: Ok, so at least this tells us that the issue relates to VS WebJobs publishing, and is not specific to Kudu.

Comment: More strange questions. my xml comments are in my nuget, but they are not moved into the bin directory along with the dll within the package. shouldn't they be?

Comment: As a work around for now, I am checking the bin directory, and if I cannot find the xml file there, I am able to access kudu's `repository\MyProject\bin` directory from the code, and grab the `CommonClassLibrary.xml` file from there. next i need to fix the `nugetClassLibrary`

Comment: Issue link: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2517